Is there a way to make a flask waitress website an HTTPS connection?
I have created a simple flask web application. I have managed to deploy it to the internet using waitress and I connected a domain name to it. My only problem is I am struggling to make the website secure (https). I have bought a SSL certificate but I don't know integrate it into the web application.
The link to my website is http://192.168.1.105/ or http://macroperspective.net/
My domain name is "macroperspective.net"
My python code is:
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "hello world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, host='192.168.1.105', port=80, url_scheme='https')

I have read the documentation of flask waitress and it seems that you can't make the web app secure using waitress. If my research is correct, I need to set up a reverse proxy server using nginx or apache. I don't really know it this is the case or how to set up a reverse proxy server.

use a reverse proxy (eg nginx)

see https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/issues/287. I find it hard to take seriously a server package that doesn't support HTTPS, but I guess waitress must do great things.

I find it very odd to try to have "https" on port 80.
Port 80 is used for HTTP connections, and port 443 for HTTPS on most websites.
As such, the common thing to happen on web servers is to listen on both port  80 and 443 for requests, with the port 80 often used just to reply with a redirect to https.
I would try to focus on that or even check from a standard Python app, how this is achieved.
Also, an 192.168.x.x IP is a local IP and not accessible over the internet.
